# How can I draw a string of text onto the pixels of a BGR image so that the text is readable when displayed, c++?

Tags: c++, image, draw

Is there a simple way to modify the pixels of a 72x72 pixel BGR image so that it contains a string of text that is readable when the image is displayed.

Essentially, I need to draw the text in `str` on the image buffer `img` created below in a way that would allow it to be read when the image is displayed.

```
unsigned char img[72*72*3]; // 72*72*3 BGR image buffer
unsigned char B = 0x00; 
unsigned char G = 0x00;
unsigned char R = 0x00;
std::string str = "Test Text";

// Create BGR image
for (int i = 0; i < (72*72*3); i += 3)
{
    img[i + 0] = B;
    img[i + 1] = G;
    img[i + 2] = R;
}

// Draw str on BGR image buffer?
```

Comment: can you use OpenCV ?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't involve using OpenCV. I know there are quite a few examples of how to do this using OpenCV cv::putText() but I was hoping for a solution that involved modifying the pixel values directly in my img buffer.

Comment: You need something which converts characters of your encoding into a pixmap. This is usually done in graphics libs. Qt can it. GDI can it as well. (OpenCV might as well.) However, all of them probably provide their own classes to represent pixmaps. If you use one of them you have to transfer (copy) produced pixels afterwards. You could prepare a set of pre-rendered characters as well which you copy into your destination image. It would be helpful if you could specify which effort you are willing to invest and what quality you expect from the outcome. (e.g. rendering text in a specific font)

Comment: Have a look at `draw_text()` in CImg... http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [CImg](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__overview.html) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // Create 72x72 RGB image
   CImg<unsigned char> image(72,72,1,3);

   // Fill with magenta
   cimg_forXY(image,x,y) {
      image(x,y,0,0)=255;
      image(x,y,0,1)=0;
      image(x,y,0,2)=255;
   }

   // Make some colours
   unsigned char cyan[]    = {0,   255, 255 };
   unsigned char black[]   = {0,   0,   0   };

   // Draw black text on cyan
   image.draw_text(3,20,"Test text",black,cyan,1,16);

   // Save result image as NetPBM PNM - no libraries required
   image.save_pnm("result.pnm");
}
```

[image]

It is small, fast, comprehensive in terms of functionality, modern C++ and *"header only"* which means you don't need to link against anything either.